# CSS3 3D image transitions combined

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, css-transitions

Hey all i have ran across this nice effect for 3d images [here](http://tympanus.net/Development/ImageTransitions/)

Problem is, i am trying to figure out how to combine ALL effects into one page instead of having a html page for each set of effects (Flip,Rotation,Multi-flip,Cube,Unfold & Others)

Could anymore let me know how to accomplish this task? It seems to use a different CSS style for each effect and i can not combine style1-6.css into one page or it will mess up all the effects.

**update**
I can currently do this:

```
$navNext.on( 'click', function( event ) {
var randNum = Math.floor ( Math.random() * wPerspective.length ) 

$type = wPerspective[randNum];
type = wPerspective[randNum];

$("LINK[href*='css/style1.css']").remove();
$("LINK[href*='css/style2.css']").remove();
$("LINK[href*='css/style3.css']").remove();
$("LINK[href*='css/style4.css']").remove();
$("LINK[href*='css/style5.css']").remove();
$("LINK[href*='css/style6.css']").remove();

var $$ = document;
var head  = $$.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var link  = $$.createElement('link');

link.id   = 'myCss';
link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.media = 'all';

console.log(type + ' | ' + type.indexOf("te-flip"));

if (type.indexOf("te-flip") == 0)
{
        link.href = 'css/style1.css';
}else if (type.indexOf("te-rotation") == 0)
{
    link.href = 'css/style2.css';
}else if (type.indexOf("te-multiflip") == 0)
{
    link.href = 'css/style3.css';
}else if (type.indexOf("te-cube") == 0)
{
    link.href = 'css/style4.css';
}else if (type.indexOf("te-unfold") == 0)
{
    link.href = 'css/style5.css';
}else if (type.indexOf("te-example") == 0)
{
    link.href = 'css/style6.css';
}

head.appendChild(link);             
$teTransition.addClass( type );

if( hasPerspective && animated )
    return false;

animated = true;    
showNext();
return false;

});
```

But its not very smooth....

**My Demo page** http://june3rdsoftware.com/trans/index.html

Comment: @ddlshack: All the effects into one page instead of each effect being a different html page.

Comment: On different images on the same page?

Comment: @ddlshack: nope, different effects on the same page.

Comment: The effects don't apply to pages, they apply to images...

Comment: @ddlshack: Check the OP for a URL of my demo

Answer (score 0):

Those are nice 3D transitions for webkit only (e.g., no Firefox). Note this is not a complete plugin solution, but proof of concept which is why it doesn't work when they are all together on the same page. Each effect can be lifted and used how you want with cross-browser versions combined.

Since they are some CSS attributes in those **style1-6.css** files that are used differently, there are **three** ways to handle this.

First method is to use `iframes` for the main page and load each `.css` file separately. The drawback is certain effects will be contained in the iframe only.

A better method will require dynamically setting the **common/base CSS styles** that are used for all effects. Those can be set via programmatic jQuery to work with the **style1-6.css** files that have only "effect" CSS rules (e.g., Flip1, Flip2, Rotate1, etc).

Another method will be to recode the **Experimental CSS3 Project** so that it's not so experimental anymore by NOT allowing for cross-script contamination of same CSS attributes. **Easy way:** Each of the 6 style sheets would then be for 6 separate `.js files`  Yes, this implies downloading the script 6 times in different flavors since you are already downloading the CSS files in 6 flavors. Each `.js file` is modded along with modding the corresponding `.css file` so no cross-contamination occurs. **Hard way:** Recode the .js file to allow for all effects without issue.

Easy Way Example:

```
<!-- The script is modded so that -1 means 1.css is used -->
<div id="te-wrapper-1" class="te-wrapper-1">

<!-- The script is modded so that -2 means 2.css is used -->
<div id="te-wrapper-2" class="te-wrapper-2">
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, arttronics. I am doing something like that. Check the OP for a URL of my demo.

Comment: To be sure it was an Answer I provided, hopefully useful. I looked at your above example and that would yet be another way to **workaround** this issue. Out of curiosity, is excluding IE9 and Firefox part of the plan? Consider using the Demo's markup in which to build a cross-browser plugin. Then again, using [**.transit**](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) jQuery Plugin with it's callback features can allow for concatenated effects too.

Comment: I now looked at the website link and see that it's very glitchy, so that method might have issues with the CSS requiring to be initialized by the plugin. Also, consider using ready to use plugins like [**jQuery Cycle**](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) that has some of the same 3D animations. Find another plugin that does the other 3D animations and then you have a library of effects to use on the webpage... both plugins can be loaded simultaneously too.